# GraphHopper integration in java spring boot with osm data imported to postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I want to build my own map server using openstreetmap. Firstly, i downloaded one country's data from osm and impoted that data to postgresql database.
And now I need to search places according given search string query (for example street name). To do that, I decided to use GraphHopper library. But I couldn't configure it with postgresql. Does anyone know how to configure GraphHopper with postgresql so that it uses postgresql as a datasource. I am building my project in spring boot. please, help me, I spent my lots of time to do it, but i didnt get any result. i appreciate any little support and help

I tried configure like that, but it didnt work:

```
@Configuration
public class GraphHopperConfiguration {
       GraphHopper graphHopper = new GraphHopperOSM().forServer();

        // Configure the PostgreSQL data source
        CmdArgs args = new CmdArgs()
                .put("graph.location", graphHopperDataDir)
                .put("datareader.file", "")
                .put("graphhopper.dataaccess", "PostgreSQL")
                .put("graphhopper.dataaccess.host", "localhost")
                .put("graphhopper.dataaccess.port", "5432")
                .put("graphhopper.dataaccess.database", "your_database_name")
                .put("graphhopper.dataaccess.user", dataSourceUsername)
                .put("graphhopper.dataaccess.password", dataSourcePassword);

        // Load the data from PostgreSQL
        graphHopper.init(args);
        graphHopper.importOrLoad();

        return graphHopper;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'did not work'? What error are you getting?